# Does anyone have examples/tutorials on how to use Bullet Physics/jBullet to do voronoi shattering?

Tags: bullet, voronoi, bulletphysics, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to get something working with jBullet physics and voronoi shattering. I can find videos galore of it working, just no code examples.

Java or C++ is fine. Just need an example of some code. Can't find a single example of doing this.

If anyone has links to good examples/tutorials I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the book "Game Physics Engine Design" has source code for a fracture demo which can be found on [Github](https://github.com/idmillington/cyclone-physics/blob/master/src/demos/fracture/fracture.cpp)